# How to deal with a double escaped xml file

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, escaping, datafeed

I am trying to process a product data feed that i download from the web, the download is done like so:

```
URL website = new URL("http://some.products.com/format/xml/compression/gzip/");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/opt/some/file.xml.gz");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
fos.close();
```

when it is saved on the file systems`&amp;#39;` and the file type seems to be ansii.

when i read the file with a streaming processor like so:

```
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("/opt/some/file.xml.gz"));
XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader eventReader = inputFactory.createXMLEventReader(gzis);
while (eventReader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = eventReader.nextEvent();
    ...
}
```

Somewhere along the way, part of the text gets decoded because in it end up like this `&#39;`

that is the escaped ampersand gets unescaped, but then it would seem the second level of escaping is not dealt with. and i cant workout how or where Im supposed to deal with it. Should i be trying to decode it when im reading the file? or should i do it after the xml as been parsed?

Edit: I should note that these characters appear in text fields, not urls.

Comment: I appear to have corrected it by passing the text to `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(text)`, from apache commons, after I have parsed it through Stax. this appears to have solved the issue, but im not sure if it is the correct way. should i use `unescapeHtml()`?

Comment: You can better put this as an answer to your question, then it dissapears from the unanswered questions.